# How can I clone from a git repository from 1 machine to another?

Tags: git

I have clone a git repository from the server on my laptop A running macosx.
I have a laptop B running linux, how can I clone from the git repository on laptop A?

How can I get the url to clone from?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you log in with ssh to laptop A from laptop B? If not, turn that on first (easiest way is to search for "ssh" in Spotlight).

Answer (score 4):

Provided you have an SSH server on laptop 1, the remote would be:

```
user@host:/path/to/repository
```

ie, type:

```
git clone user@laptopA:/path/to/repository
```

Answer (score 1):

While you can host your repo on a web server, you can keep things simple, you can share files directly and clone from the directory directly (which would be the machine filepath- \linuxbox\gitshare\myproject).

I recommend having a "main" bare repository to clone from to simplify merging if required between machines.

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup either the git daemon or ssh

Since you want to clone from Mac,

**First way** - Using git daemon, a lightweight server

1. **Mac:** Head to your repository on mac, ensure it is bare, i.e when you run `ls -lrt`, it should look like

   ```
   drwxr-xr-x   4 fooo  admin  136 21 Dec 12:26 refs
   -rw-r--r--   1 fooo  admin  205 21 Dec 12:26 packed-refs
   drwxr-xr-x   4 fooo  admin  136 21 Dec 12:26 objects
   drwxr-xr-x   3 fooo  admin  102 21 Dec 12:26 info
   drwxr-xr-x  12 fooo  admin  408 21 Dec 12:26 hooks
   -rw-r--r--   1 fooo  admin   73 21 Dec 12:26 description
   -rw-r--r--   1 fooo  admin  161 21 Dec 12:26 config
   drwxr-xr-x   2 fooo  admin   68 21 Dec 12:26 branches
   -rw-r--r--   1 fooo  admin   23 21 Dec 12:26 HEAD
   ```

   If it does not, then do step 2
2. Run `git clone --bare /<Path to your repository>`
3. Create an empty file git-daemon-export-ok: `echo '' > git-daemon-export-ok`
4. Run

   ```
   git daemon --base-path=`pwd` --verbose --port=9418
   ```
5. **Linux:** Clone your git repository:

   ```
   git clone git://<mac os ip address> <name of folder you want to check out to>
   ```

   example -

   ```
   git clone git://192.168.1.2 javaAddOn
   ```

**Second way** - Using ssh - [Slightly harder]

1. **MAC:** In Mac head to System Preferences => Remote Login
2. Open terminal to create ssh keys:

   ```
   cd ~
   ssh-keygen -t rsa    #Press enter for all default values
   cd .ssh
   cat id_rsa.pub >> authorized_keys
   ```
3. **LINUX:** Perform the same steps as in step 2, skipping creating the authorized_keys
4. Copy the authorized keys from the mac into Ubuntu under ~/.ssh/ -

   ```
   scp <macuser>@<macip>:/Users/<macuser>/.ssh/authorized_keys ~/.ssh/
   ```
5. Check to ensure you can ssh from Linux. `ssh <macuser>@<macip>`
6. If step 5 is successful you can use git.

   ```
   git clone <macuser>@<macip>:<Full Path of the repository location
   ```

example

```
    git clone pm@192.168.1:/Users/pm/repositories_git/JavaTasks
```

Finally, if you want to develop in both Mac and Linux and commit in both, you have to use the second way and then push and pull changes. I have exactly the same setup, but usually I only develop in Linux and then push the changes into Mac.

Comment: My Repository is on Windows machine and i want to clone it mac machine.
Whats steps to be followed?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that something like

```
git clone file://\\\\192.168.0.33\yourpath
```

would work